# Why does my Nikon D7200 + YN-622 TX have a one second delay when firing a studio flash?

Tags: nikon, yongnuo

I recently acquired  a D7200. I'm using The Yongnuo YN-622N TX to fire off a studio flash that I have. One thing I've noticed is that it takes a second before it fires the flash head off. I also have a D7100 and it fires it instantly. Is this normal with the D7200 or is there a way to fix this, to have it firing instantly?

P.S.

I'm using YN-622 II for the receivers

Answer (score 2):

The question is, is the shutter activation delayed too, or only the flash pop?  I assume probably both.

It could be a few things in the camera.

Probably most likely, if you have the Red Eye Reduction sync option on, that flashes the cameras front white light for about one second before the shutter and flash are triggered.  Turn that off.  See manual index for Red Eye.

Self timer could of course do it.

If you have the Exposure Delay on (menu D4 in D7200), it adds a delay before the shutter.

The ML-L3 remote shutter has delay options.

Rear Curtain Sync could do it if using a long (one second) shutter.

Comment: @tofukick Welcome to Stack Exchange. I hope you stick around and share your knowledge with others (and ask more questions when you have them). The best way to say "thanks" is to click on the upvote area to the left of an answer that helped you — and if the answer solves your problem, check the checkmark, too.

Comment: @tofukick Also, answers from the original asker that inform how an issue was ultimately solved are generally acceptable here. There are more than a few questions here where the OP has posted an answer that explained how a problem was solved.